# Ambiguity in 2d array declaration in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I have defined array in the following formats, but apparently the program works fine only in CASE B.

CASE A:

```
int **M1;
M1 = (int **)malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
for (int i=0; i<m; i++){
    M1[i] = (int *)malloc(d * sizeof(int));
}
```

CASE B:

```
int (*M1)[m] = malloc(sizeof(int[m][d]));
```

I am getting a segmentation error in CASE A. What could be the reason?

Comment: The A code works perfectly for me. What is your environment ?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the segmentation error ?

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Comment: These are two different ways to lay out an array in memory, they each have pros and cons.  The rest of your program either has a bug or is expecting only one particuar layout.  You will need to show the code that causes a segfault (preferably a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Case B should be `int (*M1)[d]`  , if `m` is the row count and `d` the column count as it is in Case A

Comment: How do you define `d`? Is it initialized?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Otherwise I'd say it's pretty unclear what's the question.

Comment: @black me too, no idea why it has upvotes

Answer (score 3):

The following code compiles without error or warning in `gcc` compiler,

```
    int **M1,i;
    M1 = (int **)malloc(5 * sizeof(int *));
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        M1[i] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    }
    M1[0][0]=111;
    M1[0][1]=222;
    printf("\n%d %d",M1[0][0],M1[0][1]);
```

Gives `111 222` as output.

The problem might be some where else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

CASE A;

`M1` is a pointer to a pointer.
You are allocating memory for a 2D array of type int and you can store `m*d` values in the array.

`M1[0][0]` to `M[m-1][d-1]` are valid access for this array in order to get value of type `int` and anything other than this will lead to undefined behavior.

Case B:

M1 is a pointer to an array of type int which has `m` elements.

In Case A, the segmentation fault most likely looks like is because of array out of bound access

Comment: No, he allocates memory for `m` number of `int*`, which is perfectly fine. It's also perfectly fine to access `M1[0]`, you just get an `int*`, not an `int`.

Comment: @Jite I think you misunderstood my answer. Yeah `int *` is fine but I meant the valid int values accessible are `M1[0][0]` to `M1[4][4]`

Comment: Where do you get `[4][4]` from? We don't know the value of `m` nor `d`?

Comment: @Jite Very sorry about it. Yeah you are right in that regard

Comment: `M1[m-1]` is the upper end for retreiving `int*` while in this case `M1[m-1][d-1]` is the upper end for retreiving `int` values (from the second malloc).

Comment: @Jite I overlooked `d` :) somehow `m*m` was picked :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86860/discussion-between-gopi-and-jite).

Answer (score 1):

A pointer and an array are different things.
A pointer to a type holds the address where a variable of declared type is allocated.

An array of a type is a memory space where variables of the declared type are **contiguously stored**.

Now you're declaration. There is no ambiguity (even if is not so evident) in C declarations.
In case **A** you have declared:

```
int **M1;
```

This is not a 2d array, not even a monodimensional one. You are declaring a variable, `M!`, as a pointer to another pointer to an int. In plane word `M1` will hold the address of another variable that in turn holds the address of where in memory is stored an integer.
Now executing:

```
M1 = (int **)malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
```

You assign to `M1` the address of **a memory area that can store up to m contiguous integer pointers**, an access to memory pointed by `M1`, and successive locations **acts as an array access** (but is not). This is more or less equivalent to the static declaration:

```
int *[m];    //an array of pointers to int
```

Then assigning each element of this pseudo-array a memory storage for `d` contiguous integers:

```
for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    M1[i] = (int *)malloc(d * sizeof(int));
}
```

you now have room to store `d` consecutive integers that begins at addresses saved in `M1[i]` for i=0->d-1.

What happens when you try to access a value using subscripts: `M1[a][b]`?
The compiler retrieve the address pointed by `M1` and using the first subscript (`a`), retrieves the contents pointed by the address in the atht position of the pointers array. This points to the first integer of the subspace that we have allocated to hold `d` consecutive int's. This is indeed a monodimensional array of int. Applying the second subscript to it the compiler finally retrieve the required integer. Cose to a bidimensional array addressing, but no banana! It isn't a bidimensional array of int's. :-)

In case **B** you are declaring **a pointer to a monodimensional array of int**, to which you are assigning enough space to hold your bidimensional array. Because in C doesn't exist the concept of multidimensional array, but a basic principle of array of array of array.... etc. (ad-libitum), the declaration:

```
int (*M1)[m] = malloc(sizeof(int[m][d]));
```

as a pointer to modimensiional array with space allocated for an array of `[m][d]` elements made the trick.

**But of course both the solutions are wrong!**

You are using side effects to obtain what you want, but using surrogates of what you declared to need: a bidimensional array of int's.

**The correct solution is to define a pointer to a bidimensional array of integers** where only the first subscript is required:

```
int (*M1)[][m];    //declare a pointer to a real array

M1 = malloc(m * d * sizeof(int));    //Allocate room for bidimensional array

for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<d; j++)
    {
        (*M1)[i][j] = (i*100)+j;    //Fill elements with something using bidimensional subscripting
    }
for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<d; j++)
    {
        printf("[%d][%d]=%d\n", i, j, (*M1)[i][j]);    //Check back data...
    }
```

Now have a look to what happens if you go out bounds in the 3 cases.
In case **A** if you get out of bounds with the first subscript **you'll collect a wrong pointer that will cause immediately a memory fault**, in case **B** you will have memory fault only if you go out of process addressable memory, the same for the correct solution.
**This should answer to your question**.

Last, because we are talking of misunderstandigs about arrays and pointers, don't misinterpret the standard ISO 9899:2011§6.7.6.3/7 that says:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
>   ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are
>   those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If
>   the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type
>   derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
>   corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
>   element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
>   size expression.

It simply states that **arrays will be passed only by reference (automatically adjusted by compiler), never by value (that is legal for structs ie)**. You are not requested to supply any qualified pointer instead of an array in function call or the program will crash (**A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
‘‘qualified pointer to type’’ - means that will be adjusted by compiler, not by you**). Cases as `char *[]` and `char **` works for the reason reported above, not because it is legal to exchange them!